# How can I use two Devise's before_filters in one rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If I have two roles in my application,one is admin,another is user,and now I want to give both of them the ability to visit  controller actions  , how should I do this?

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter is used here,but how?
  def methodA     #index  or new...
    ...
  end
  def methodB     #show  or  edit...
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

There are some helpers that created by Devise:

```
before_filter :authenticate_admin! 

admin_signed_in?

current_admin

admin_session
```

And in these helpers ,"admin" can be changed to "user".

Comment: `before_filter :must_be_admin_or_user, :only => [:methodA, :methodB]`. Then define that method which returns true if the user is of any of those roles.

Comment: @kiddorails: Don't think this will work since ":only" option is used to only skip this filter for actions not methods,

Comment: This will work. Whenever the controller is asked to call these actions, it will be validated by `must_be_admin_or_user`

Comment: @kiddorails Thanks! It works.Your way gave me a right direction to thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, you have a devise model. Each account is flagged (somehow) as user or admin. So as long as a visitor is authenticated, s/he is allowed to access the controller's methods.

In your controller, add
`before_filter: authenticate_user!`
(if your devise model is called 'user'), it should be enough.

Now if you have two models (one for each role), you can try this:

```
before_filter :deny_to_visitors

private

def deny_to_visitors
  redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in? or admin_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: Exactly! I wonder why there is so much confusion about this?  I asked @xwyy to do the same in very first comment.

Comment: Thanks! Your method  is beautiful  and  powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. Devise is mostly used for authentication, but cancan is better to deal with user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking. Are the `methods A & B` controller actions? If so, the helpers that are generated by Devise use the appropriate model name. Example:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_model_name!
```

So if you have a `User model` and `Admin model`, you can use both:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:destroy, etc]
before_filter :authenticate_admin!, only: [:destroy, etc]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is working since the two conditions cannot be true at the same time

Comment: It kind of sounds like you may want permissions. Take a look at [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Comment: What I'm saying is that this would require the user to sign in both as user and admin. I don't really get the link with cancan here?

Answer (score -1):

How about this: use one method, but inside that method call 2nd method.

```
before_filter :methodA

def methodA  
   #call method B from here
end


def methodB  
   return true | false or something
end
```

Comment: This is absurd. You are supposing them to be methods; and calling one from another? Why? @xwyy is asking for way that those one of those two roles(conditions) are satisfied to reach in those controllers. Read about [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Comment: I won't waste time to argue with @kiddo. Docs state, exactly what i wrote above. You're trying to call two methods not two actions from before filter: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html